# Search wordpress using three different drop down menus

Tags: wordpress, search, drop-down-menu

I have three drop down menus that are chained together. Year, Make Model. I need wordpress search results to show their matching results. If I give them all the name="s" then it only searches the final s= in the url.

**I basically need to know how to make**

mysite.com/?s=2001&s=Chevrolet&s=Express&Search=Search

**turn into:**

mysite.com/?s=2001+Chevrolet+Express&Search=Search

**or whatever gets the job done.**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not name the selects.  Instead, give them ids and make a hidden form field, then use javascript to update the hidden field.

```
function updateHiddenField(){
    var year = document.getElementById("YearDD").value; //this is conceptual
    var make = document.getElementById("MakeDD").value; //this is conceptual
    var model = document.getElementById("ModelDD").value; //this is conceptual
    document.getElementById("s").value = year+"+"+make+"+"+model; //this is conceptual
}
```

Then later...

```
<input type="hidden" name="s" id="s" value="">
<select id="YearDD" onChange="updateHiddenField();">
...
```

Otherwise you could overwrite the "Submit" Button, generate your own query string/url and redirect the page.

Or, in a real dirty way, you could just search the string and convert "&s=" with "+".

Comment: Thanks, im having trouble trying to implement that code. Honestly, I've spent too much time on this project as is...could you direct me to the page i need to edit to do it the "dirty way?"

Comment: Just got into work this morning and tried it out. It works like a charm! :D Only think way I had to take out "alert(document.getElementById("s").value);" It gave me an alert everytime I made a selection, however this did NOT happen in the tinkerbin you sent me. Works just fine without it though! THANKS!